# Updating state with nested array of objects without mutation

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to update my state. I want to be able to update a specific isChecked property when it is updated when a user clicks a checkbox. My state below:

```
this.state = {
    userPermissions: [
    {
      appName: "Dashboard",
      roles: [
        {
          appId: "1",
          statusId: 1,
          isChecked: false
        },
        {
          appId: "1",
          statusId: 2,
          isChecked: true
        },
      ]
    },
    {
      appName: "Finance",
      roles: [
        {
          appId: "2",
          statusId: 3,
          isChecked: false
        },
        {
          appId: "2",
          statusId: 4,
          isChecked: true
        },
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

This is what I have tried. I have to map twice to get to the roles and then set the conditions, however, I am assuming I am mutating the state with another new one so when I render it, it breaks.

```
handleCheck = (e, data) => {
  const checked = e.target.checked;

  this.setState(prevState => ({
    userPermissions: prevState.userPermissions
      .map(item => item.roles
        .map(item => item.appId === data.appId && item.statusId === data.statusId ? { ...item, isChecked: checked } : item))
      }))
  }
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this without mutation? Thanks.

Comment: Is there a cleaner way? Probably. I see what looks like duplication of state. This tells me that the React that's using this state is probably monolithic. This looks like it should be broken down into 2 components, Dashboard and Frontend. These are really 2 instances of the same component, each component would its own `appName` and `appId` as props. These components would also have children, probably again several instances of the same component. Each of those would have `statusId` as a prop and `isChecked` as state. but maybe that's not possible in your use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone has issues with this in the future, I have posted the way I have solved this. I feel this is a cleaner solution.

```
const { userPermissions } = this.state;
const { checked } = e.target;

//find the app index
const appIndex = userPermissions.findIndex(element => element.appName === data.appName);

//find the status index
const roleIndex = userPermissions[appIndex].roles.findIndex(role => role.statusId=== data.statusId);

//create a copy of state
let newArr = [...userPermissions];

//make change on isChecked
newArr[appIndex].roles[roleIndex] = { ...newArr[appIndex].roles[roleIndex], isChecked: checked };

this.setState({
  userPermissions: newArr
})
```

Answer (score 0):

your object changes to this after you run it through your maps [image]

```
this.setState((state) => {
  const { userPermissions } = state;
const index = userPermissions.findIndex(e => e.roles.findIndex(ee => ee.appId === "1")!= -1)
const roleIndex = userPermissions[index].roles.findIndex(role => role.appId === "1")
  return {
    ...state,
    userPermissions: [
      ...userPermissions.slice(0, index),
      Object.assign(
        { ...userPermissions.slice[index] },
        {
          roles: [
            ...userPermissions[index].roles.slice(0, roleIndex),
            Object.assign(userPermissions[index].roles[roleIndex], {
              isChecked: !userPermissions[index].roles[roleIndex].isChecked
            }),
            ...userPermissions[index].roles.slice(roleIndex + 1)
          ]
        }
      ),
      ...userPermissions.slice(index + 1)
    ]
  };
});
```

Comment: can you explain how this works or where to input this information? Thanks.

Comment: map returns an array so you are basically changing the shape of your object. You are basically getting an array of length 2 because map always returns the same length of elements as what you are calling on behalf of and each array is returning the roles objects as an array

Comment: the above does not work for me. I am getting a bunch of errors because of index and roleIndex is not defined.

Comment: kk defined them for you, try it now

Answer (score 0):

```
let state = {
   keys: ['Finance', 'Dashboard'],
   Finance: [
      {
         appId: '2',
         statusId: 3,
         isChecked: false,
      },
      {
         appId: '2',
         statusId: 4,
         isChecked: true,
      },
   ],
   Dashboard: [
      {
         appId: '1',
         statusId: 1,
         isChecked: false,
      },
      {
         appId: '1',
         statusId: 2,
         isChecked: true,
      },
   ],
};

this.setState(prev => {
   let Finance = prev.Finance.map(item =>
      item.appId === data.appId && item.statusId === data.statusId
         ? { ...item, isChecked: checked }
         : item
   );
   let Dashboard = prev.Dashboard.map(item =>
      item.appId === data.appId && item.statusId === data.statusId
         ? { ...item, isChecked: checked }
         : item
   );
   return {
      keys: prev.keys,
      Finance,
      Dashboard,
   };
});
```

I have changed your state structure,I think it is more readable and you can read the state object and debug it much better

Comment: the app names have to be dynamic since in the future I could have more than two apps. Is there another way? Thanks.

Comment: you can add another app to the list, the keys array is just for the same reason and add the object based on the array